# How to quickly project certain columns from a map?

Tags: c++, sql, dictionary, stl

I'm writing an SQL interpreter.
I've chosen to store my tuples as an array (`vector` actually) of `map`s.
Each tuple of a table is a `map`. The key is attribute name and the value is the value of that attribute.
I must support operations such as `project`.

So I must implement such a method as:

```
Table Table::project(const vector<string> &attributes) {
  // return a Table with just the attributes passed
}
```

in the Table class which takes the attributes to be projected and returns a new table with just those attributes.

The only way I can think of doing this is:

```
Table Table::project(const vector<string> &attributes) {
  // iterate through each tuple of the current table. For each tuple,
  // iterate through all attributes passed, find the value of each one in
  // the current tuple and add it to the new tuple. Insert the new tuple into
  // the new table. Return the table.
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
Should I be using a better data structure?

Comment: C++ has `std::tuple`, `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::map` (plus other classes/containers). Why don't you just give us **the real type** instead of a fuzzy description of the type?

Comment: @DanielFrey, What real type?

Comment: @DanielFrey, If you meant what type each attribute is, I've made that `boost::any`. So, each tuple is `map<string, boost::any>`.